# Changing the value in a cell in a different workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a little stuck trying to store a value in a cell in another open workbook. I'm getting a subscript out of range error", so clearly I'm not pointing to this cell correctly.  Here is what I have:

```
    Workbooks(wbSource).Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheet32.Range("currMth").Value = Me.cboCurrMth.Value
```

wbSource is a string that holds the name of the target workbook ("myfile.xls" for example). I'm confident that that is defined and set correctly.

I've tried lots of different ways to store this value, but nothing works. This is just one of my attempts. I'd prefer to not even activate this workbook if I can just populate it from the workbook where the code is written.

Can anybody see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Sheet32 needs to be sheets(32)... On the condition that 32 is the index of the sheet.

Comment: Are you sure `Sheet32` exists? That would be quite a few worksheets in a single workbook...

Comment: Yes. it is a very large workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) What is Sheet32?
2.) I am not sure that you can index Ranges by name.

The following works:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks ("t1.xlsx")
wb.Names("MyRange").RefersToRange.Value2 = 5
```

Comment: Thanks for this reply. This works for changing the value, which is what I asked about. What I didn't mention since I was trying to keep the problem statement as brief as possible, is that I first need to unprotect the worksheet before I can write a value to it. So I still need a way to actually set the focus onto sheet32 so that I can do "sheet32.unprotect" (or something along those lines). Sorry that I didn't mention this earlier.

Comment: I should clarify that if I use the name of the sheet (as changed by the user), my code works. It's only when I want to use the internal name that it won't work. So, for example wb.worksheets("myname").unprotect will work, but wb.worksheets(Sheet32).unprotect does not work. Weird.

Comment: Is Sheet32 a variable? If so, I would try Sheet32.unprotect.

Comment: That was of my first attempts. I figured that once I had the workbook activated, I could just do sheet32.unprotect. But it doesn't work for some reason. It doesn't throw an error on the unprotect line, but then when I try to update that cell, it crashes because the sheet is still protected. I'm just going to use the sheet name since that seems to work. Thanks for your help. I appreciate it.